# Can you travel to Canada or Australia if you're inadmissible to the US?

Tags: visas, usa, canada, australia

My friend has been inadmissible to the US since 2009 due to misrepresentation, but got married in 2013 to a US citizen, while his visa is still denied after 8 years. Can he travel to Canada or Australia?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. There is no legal bar stopping him from traveling to any other country as long as he meets the visa requirements. However,  both countries ask in their respective visa applications if the applicant has been refused entry/removed/refused visa to any other country. That will arouse suspicion and there is a chance that his visa will be denied on that basis. He could try and lie but if he's caught he can forgot about travelling to any [FCC countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Country_Conference).